# Convert values from array in json object using bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, echo, jq

I am totaly new to shell..... let me ut the proper use case.
Use case:- 
I have written two get method in my shell script, and when a user calls that script I will perform some operation for many id's using a for loop. like below

```
test_get1(){

value1=//performing some operation and storing it
value2=//performing some operation and storing it

//below line I am converting the o/p of value1 and value2 in json

value=$JQ_TOOL -n --arg key1 "$value1" --arg key2 "$value2" '{"key1":"\($value1)","key2":"\($value2)"}'

}

test_get2(){
arr=(1,2,3)
local arr_values=()
for value in arr
do 
// Calling test_get1 for each iteraion of this loop, like below
val=$(test_get1 $value)
//below line will store the values in array
arr_values+=("$val")
done 
}
```

When I am doing echo for the above arr_values, I am getting the below output
Output.

```
arr_values={
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
    }
    {
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
    }
```

I want to convert the above value in json format like below.

```
json_value=[
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2"
},
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2"
}
]
```

I tried to do it with JQ, but unable to get the proper result.

Comment: post the actual valid input json structure

Comment: Your input `arr_values` isn't even a valid JSON

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have updated the question

Comment: @umesh, `LS=/usr/bin/ls` and the like is an antipattern -- a bad practice held over from people who copied things they saw in scripts written for 1970s-era shells that didn't cache PATH lookups. There's absolutely no value to it here -- *if* you needed to override `jq`, you'd be better off defining a wrapper function; using a variable just decreases readability and (if that variable contains an absolute path) decreases portability across machines.

Comment: (...whereas if your goal is to run from a cron job on a system where crond's default PATH doesn't contain the location of your local `jq` binary, the right thing is to *define a PATH in your crontab file*; ie. by putting a line `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` up before the specifications).

Answer (score 1):

Use the slurp option:

```
jq -s . in.json > out.json
```

**in.json**

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

**out.json**

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
]
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your existing "value=" line can be simplified to:

```
value=$(jq -n --arg key1 "$value1" --arg key2 "$value2" '\
   {key1: $value1, key2: $value2}')
```

because `--arg` always interprets the provided value as a string, and because jq expressions need not follow all the rules of JSON.

2) From your script, arr_value is a bash array of JSON values.  To convert it into a JSON array, you should be able to use an incantation such as:

```
for r in "${a[@]}" ; do printf "%s" "$r" ; done | jq -s .
```

3) There is almost surely a much better way to achieve your ultimate goal. Perhaps it would help if you thought about calling jq just once.